# Jekyll Liquid: use truncatewords filter on a whole included file

Tags: templates, jekyll, liquid

Is there a way in Jekyll with Liquid, to include another file and truncate the number of words from it?

```
{{ {% include intro.md %} | truncatewords: 3 }}
```

No matter how I set the curly braces, no luck...

Including intro.md alone works:

```
{% include intro_DE.md %}
```

Here is a [vague note](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/169#issuecomment-52434539), that include might be a bit different under Jekyll, but I still have no clue...

Perhaps, I need to go through [capture](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/liquid-for-designers#variable-assignment)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution with capture. It just not very elegant:

```
{% capture foo %}{% include intro_DE.md %}{% endcapture %}
{{ foo | truncatewords: 20 }}
```

The output is still markdown-ish (=good). “Inline-styles“ like bold, underline, strikethrough still work.

`### Headlines` and `<html tags>` don't. (Probably because this technique kills the linefeeds...)

Answer (score 0):

"truncatewords" works only for string datatype,
for example: If we have to use limited words on card description then it is good practice to use truncatewords.
[for more please read this] https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/truncatewords/